# javascript array optimization

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I have multiple array items nested inside each other and cashed data i want to call, i want to know if there is a way i can do the following. As i want to reduce my total number of variables.

```
 //function to check for change 
   function dataChange(oldData, newData){
   if(oldData > newData){
      alert('change');
     }
   }


//current code   
 var num1 = item[key]['b02'][0];
 var num2 = item[key]['b02'][1];
 var numOld1 = itemOld[key]['b02'][0];
 var numOld2 = itemOld[key]['b02'][1];

 dataChange(num1,numOld1);


//proposed code
 var num1 = ['b02'][0];
 var num2 = ['b02'][1];

dataChange(item[key].num1, itemOld[key].num1);
```

Comment: please add the content of `item`, `itemOld` and `key` as well.

Comment: its really long, but i will try

Comment: @Paddy: See [mcve], emphasis on **minimal** but also **complete**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any variables at all other than `item`, `itemOld`, and `key`:

```
dataChange(item[key]['b02'][0], itemOld[key]['b02'][0]);
```

which can also be written

```
dataChange(item[key].b02[0], itemOld[key].b02[0]);
```

But since `item[key]['b02']` and `item[key]['b02']` are objects, you can also use variables to refer to them and then just use `[0]` and `[1]`:

```
var current = item[key]['b02'];
var old = itemOld[key]['b02'];

dataChange(current[0], old[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always have the following structure, you could simply implement a function in the following way:

```
function dataChange(x, xk1, xk2, y, yk1, yk2) {
    return x[xk1][xk2] > y[yk1][yk2];
}

dataChange(item[key], 'b02', 0, itemOld[key], 'b02', 2);
```